# The fuzzy line between hardware and software

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, closed-questions

**Background to the questions:**
It is true that stackoverflow is only for software related issues.  However software is purely academic without hardware that runs it.

There was a post recently which was about a low power design [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578828/low-power-sensor-module)  that I would argue although badly asked was a legitimate discussion on low power software design techniques and should not have been closed.  I would postulate this because it did not mention any particular hardware, more how to work out what hardware and software could be combined to use XBee, a software protocol work.

Of course there are other questons I would agree have no links to software so should be moved.

I think the problem is partly down to the success of stackoverflow. A web on a technical topic ofen returns a stackoverflow result where permitted tags are [electronics](/questions/tagged/electronics) and [hardware](/questions/tagged/hardware).  It is not surprising that people often post in the wrong place.  I was not aware of there being an electroncs.stackexchange before I started my first post here, and the I only stumbled across it after a post was closed.

IMO not enough is done to make people aware of the other systems. Or allow messages to be moved between them.

Perhaps there should be a move to either allow more hardware or electronics posting where they can be argued to have a software link.  A software engineering topic in the answer, or there should be a button to MOVE to another forum, rather than bluntly closing it.

***So to my questions:***

Why are there not better links between stackoverflow and electronics?

Why are people too hasty to close qustions as being 'off topic' when that might only be the view of a few?  Perhaps voting to close should be open to a more balanced forum of hardware and software engineers?

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion, [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578828/low-power-sensor-module) was probably closed for the wrong reason. Instead of being closed as "off topic", it should have been closed as "not constructive". Note that the actual question being asked is this one (emphasis added):

> Basically, what is the **best** low power wireless module out there?

That's not a good fit for Stack Overflow. We don't answer questions of the form "What is the best...?" [Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128562#128562). It doesn't handle subjective questions, or those where any answer is equally valid. This is all covered in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq/), in particular [the section concerning the types of questions which you should not ask](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

If you think that question should be re-opened and closed as "not constructive" in order to send a more appropriate message to the community, I'm sure the moderator who closed it would be happy to oblige.

> Perhaps there should be a move to either allow more hardware or electronics posting where they can be argued to have a software link.

I don't really know why we need to have a *movement*, and I don't know what this movement would *consist* of, were we to have one. **Questions about hardware *as it relates to computer programming* are and have always been allowed.** If people ask these types of questions, they can be upvoted and answered. That's the customary way we move on Stack Overflow.

> A software engineering topic in the answer, or there should be a button to MOVE to another forum, rather than bluntly closing it.

1. Stack Overflow is not a forum.
2. There *is* a button (well, it's actually more like a link) to move a question to a more appropriate site in the Stack Exchange network, if it is off-topic on the site which it is asked, if it is a good fit on the new site, and if it is well-asked and deserving of migration. We do not, however, dump our crap on other people's sites.
3. Closing is not any more "blunt" than anything else we could do. Migration has been criticized as being "blunt" or "unfeeling" or other such things, but we're in the business of Q&A, not coddling. Moreover, note that closed questions can be and often are re-opened. The whole point of closure is to give the question a chance to be rewritten to comply with our guidelines, either by the original asker or by other knowledgeable community members.

> Why are there not better links between stackoverflow and electronics?

What "links" are you looking for? The questions we have are those questions that people ask. If no one is asking good questions about electronics *as they relate to computer programming*, then we don't have [m]any of these questions.

If you want to solve this problem and send some kind of message that these questions are allowed, then you need to ask more of this type of question!

> Perhaps voting to close should be open to a more balanced forum of hardware and software engineers?

It is. Voting to close is an option open to [*everyone* with 3,000 reputation or more](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions). Perhaps more importantly, voting to *re-open* closed questions is a privilege available to that same group of users.

The question to which you linked hasn't received any re-open votes since it was closed 5 days ago.